SP-API Inbound FBA Shipment Notification
I cannot seem to find a way to retrieve inbound shipment information when a new inbound shipment is created. The only way to do it is to setup a cronjob that runs at specific times. I'm looking for a more dynamic solution; is there an alert I can use under the SP-API that will send a notification when an inbound FBA shipment is created?
I searched through the SP-API documentation, but cannot seem to find anything that addresses my problem.

If you need to understand when an inbound shipment has been created, unfortunately there is actually no push notification that alerts you when a new Inbound Shipment plan has been created. But there may be a workaround on this.
Indeed if you check the Notification section of Amazon SP-API and, in particular, the NotificationType section, you won't find anything for FBA except for:

FBA Inventory Availability Changes
FBA Outbound Shipment Status

So, right now, what you can do is either:

poll the listInboundPlans, which is probably what you are currently do, otherwise
subscribe to the FBA Inventory Availability Changes and, when you see a change in the InboundQuantityBreakdown go and retrieve Inbound Plans, since you know that something is going to be received.

